# View log files of crashed pods in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Any idea to view the log files of a crashed pod in kubernetes?
My pod is listing it's state as "CrashLoopBackOff" after started the replicationController. I search the available docs and couldn't find any.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Assuming that your pod **still exists:**

`kubectl logs <podname> --previous`

> $ kubectl logs -h
> -p, --previous[=false]: If true, print the logs for the previous instance of the container in a pod **if it exists**.

Comment: Not work for me: `Error from server (NotFound): pods "my-service" not found`

Comment: it returns nothing.

Comment: Try `kubectl logs <podname> --namespace <some_namespace>`.  If you don't know your namespace use `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` to find your pod and its namespace.

Comment: Is there way how to get logs from pre-previous pod?

Answer (score 19):

In many cases, `kubectl logs <podname> --previous` is returning:

```
Error from server (BadRequest): previous terminated container "<container-name>" in pod "<pod-name>" not found
```

So you can try to check in the namespace's events (`kubectl get events ..`) like @alltej showed.

If you don't find the reason for the error with `kubectl logs / get events` and you can't view it with external logging tool I would suggest:

**1 )** Check on which node that pod was running on with:

```
$kubectl get -n <namespace> pod <pod-name> -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,STATUS:.status.phase,NODE:.spec.nodeName

NAME              STATUS    NODE
failed-pod-name   Pending   dns-of-node
```

(If you remove the `<pod-name>` you can see other pods in the namespace).

**2 )** SSH into that node and:

A )  Search for the failed pod container name in `/var/log/containers/` and dump its `.log` file and search for errors - in most of the cases the cause of error will be displayed there alongside with the actions / events that took place before the error.

B ) If previous step doesn't help try searching for latest System level errors by running: 
 `sudo journalctl -u kubelet -n 100 --no-pager`.

Comment: If you want to do an SSH into the node in AKS, you can do as follows:
`kubectl debug node/aks-nodepool1-12345678-vmss000000 -it --image=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime-deps:6.0` followed by `chroot /host`, see
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/node-access

Answer (score 16):

`kubectl logs` command only works if the pod is up and running. If they are not, you can use the `kubectl events` command.

```
kubectl get events -n <your_app_namespace> --sort-by='.metadata.creationTimestamp'
```

By default it does not sort the events, hence the `--sort-by` flag.

Comment: This only lists the events, it does not provide logs about _why_ there was a backoff

Answer (score 8):

There was a bug in kubernetes that prevents logs obtaining for pods in CrashLoopBackOff state. Looks like it was fixed. Here [issue on github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/16507) with additional information

Answer (score 3):

If the pod does not exist anymore:

```
kubectl describe pod {RUNTIME_NAME_OF_POD}
```

In the output you should have the section "Events" which contains the error messages that prevented the pod to start.

Answer (score 3):

Container Failures could be due to resource limits reached:

```
State:          Waiting
  Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
Last State:     Terminated
  Reason:       OOMKilled
  Exit Code:    137
  Started:      Wed, 18 Jan 2023 11:28:14 +0530
  Finished:     Wed, 18 Jan 2023 11:28:18 +0530
Ready:          False
Restart Count:  13
```

OR

The application ended due to an error:

```
State:          Waiting
  Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
Last State:     Terminated
  Reason:       Error
  Exit Code:    2
  Started:      Wed, 18 Jan 2023 11:50:59 +0530
  Finished:     Wed, 18 Jan 2023 11:51:03 +0530
Ready:          False
```

Debugging container failure:

```
# Looking at pod status which will contain the above status information:
kubectl get pod POD_NAME -o yaml

# Watch the events to specific pod:
kubectl get events -w | grep POD_NAME_STRING

# For default container logs: Tailing the logs may give clue
kubectl logs -f POD_NAME

# For specific container: reason for application failure
kubectl logs -f POD_NAME --container CONTAINER_NAME

# only view logs of a crashed/restarted: 
kubectl logs <POD_NAME> --previous

# Get logs of multiple pods with this label:
kubectl logs -l app=blue-green  


# Looking at events:
kubectl describe deployment DEPLOYMENT_NAME
kubectl describe pod POD_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

[As discussed on another StackOverflow question, I wrote an open source tool to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70562217/495995)

[image]

The main difference with the other answers is that this is triggered automatically when a pod crashes, so it can help avoid scenarios where you start debugging this much later on and the pod itself no longer exists and logs can't be fetched.