# Running local docker image in Minikube

Tags: docker, minikube

I have set up Docker for Windows and minikube. Example listed here for (k8s.gcr.io/echoserver:1.10) works just fine: 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/.

However when I create simple .NET MVC app under c:\dev\helloworld and try to run in in Minikube I get status: **CrashLoopBackOff**

Environment: Windows 10 Enterprise

Please help. What do i need to set up to make this work?
[image: u]

Comment: Can you show us the app source code? Chances are you have an error in the app, or it terminates without ever attaching a TTY, per this article: https://www.krenger.ch/blog/crashloopbackoff-and-how-to-fix-it/

Comment: You may gain some insight by running it only in Docker without Kubernetes. Also, check the suggestions in the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44702715/kubernetes-pod-fails-with-crashloopbackoff

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you target the Docker daemon running in the minikube VM when you run `docker build` instead of the Docker for Windows daemon running on the host, then the minikube Docker will have access to that image and subsequent `kubectl run` commands will work as desired.  I'm not sure exactly which commands to run on Windows, but on a POSIX system like Macs or Linux you can run:

```
# make 'docker' commands use daemon in minikube
eval $(minikube docker-env)

# build image so that minikube Docker daemon has it
docker build -t hello-world:v1 .

# deploy to kubernetes
kubectl run hello-world --image=hello-world:v1 --port=8080

# unset DOCKER environment variables so it goes back to 
# targetting the usual Docker for Windows
eval $(minikube docker-env -u)
```

I don't know if `eval` is the right thing to run on Windows, but if you just run `minikube docker-env` it will likely give you some instructions, e.g. for me it gives:

```
$ minikube docker-env
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.103:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/amitgupta/.minikube/certs"
# Run this command to configure your shell:
# eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

Comment: yes. that worked. In Windows Power Shell you do: PS C:\minikube> minikube docker-env. after that you should see a list of images in minikube, including the newly build docker image.  Also, in deployment file: imagePullPolicy: Never