# Pods is getting crashed in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

My Pod is getting crashed and restarting multiple time while deploying my java application using kubernetes cluster.

I am able to run small micro services using kubernetes pod.

While creating pod I am getting the below exception:

```
Warning BackOff         Back-off restarting failed docker container
    24s   10s     2       {kubelet 192.168.1.31}
Warning FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for
    "enliven" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 1m20s restarting failed
    container=enliven pod=enliven_default(75d49b7a-d36f-11e7-9800-0021f6220722)"
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Get the output from kubectl logs -f podname  as described by others. Also what does kubectl get events -n YourNameSpace show?

Answer (score 1):

You could start by checking the logs on the pod, to see if the application is failing to start for whatever reason. You can do that using

```
kubectl logs your_pod_name --previous
```

One potential problem that I'd take look at, is if your Java application is taking more resources than are available/allowed on the cluster. [Here you can see how requests and limits work](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/). But your pod may had been killed by Kubernetes due to this very reason: too much resources usage.

Comment: Where It will store the log. When I type kubectl logs MyPODName it is not showing any logs. Secondly my image size is around 750MB is that causing for crashing my pod.

Comment: The resources have nothing to do with the size of the image. It's about CPU and memory requirements of your Java application. Check this link to get the logs of the killed pod https://stackoverflow.com/a/34097447/563072

Comment: Still my pod is getting crashed. logs it is not generating. But when I describe the pod it is coming  FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "httpd" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 20s restarting failed container=httpd pod=httpd_default(f8ae7061-d4fb-11e7-9800-0021f6220722)"

Comment: How are you creating the pod?

Comment: I am creating pod through YAML file. This is my file apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  # name of Pod
  name: httpd
  labels:
    # rabel of Pod
    app: web_server
spec:
  containers:
    # name of Container
  - name: httpd
    # Container image
    image: dockeratramyam/kubernetes-publisher
    ports:
      # Container Port
    - containerPort: 80

Comment: Please, add it to your question with proper formatting, and add the command you are using to create it.

Comment: # kubectl create -f pod.yaml  In that YAML file I have mentioned my docker image.

Comment: The issue got resolved when I add the below command in my yaml file.   command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
args: [ "while true; do sleep 30; done;" ]

Answer (score 0):

In case of pod's container, you need to keep alive your main process to running your pod or container. If the main process is died or finished the pod will get retstarted or crashed. If you have a binary of your application just use that in your docker files entrypoint. or else you can go ahead with sleep command but if you are running a server it's best practice to keep it as main process by entering it in entrypoint.
in case of using sleep  add this  in  pod's container spec

```
containers:
  command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ] 
  args: [ "while true; do sleep 5; done;" ]
```